# I want to update table value based on another table max value

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables A and B(oracle database). Table B has two columns Id and mdate, where id is primary key. Table A has two columns Id and mdate where id is foreign key. I want to update table B mdate value which should be max mdate value from table A for matching Id.

```
Update b
set mdate= (select max(mdate) from a group by Id) 
where b.id = a.id;
```

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: You have tagged both MySQL and Oracle. Which is it?

Comment: Move `WHERE b.id = a.id` into the subquery.

Comment: Rdbms is oracle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. The `WHERE` clause needs to be moved into the subquery, to make it a correlated subquery. Also, the parameter to `UPDATE` is a table name, not a column name.

```
UPDATE b
SET mdate = (SELECT MAX(mdate) FROM a WHERE b.id = a.id)
```

In MySQL you can also do it with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE b
JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(mdate) AS mdate
      FROM a
      GROUP BY id) AS a ON a.id = b.id
SET b.mdate = a.mdate
```

Comment: Can you please suggest solution for mysql also because in mysql I am getting error.(yet to check in oracle)

Comment: I've added the `JOIN` version that I would use in MySQL. What error were you getting ?

Comment: Above oracle query is working fine, but the only issue is   that it is updating non matching id mdate as null. I have got a solution for same below

Answer (score 0):

```
Update b 
set(b.mdate) = (select MAX(a.mdate) from a where b.id = a.id) 
where exists ( select 1 from a where b.id = a.id);
```

Thanks to Mr. Barmar.